# Illustrator basic shape build

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

[image]

How do you get a shape like this (excuse the hand drawing but it gives you a visual):

Width: 7 inches

Height: 5.1 inches from the middle, but as it goes to the left and right it ends at 2.75"

How to setup and get this shape?

Thank you and please excuse my absolute lack of knowledge.

Comment: Duplicate post: [Custom Size in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137707/custom-size-in-illustrator)

Comment: Probably no reason to close this question because he posted an exact duplicate, but I just wanted to publicly shame OP for leaving his previous question to rot and then just lazily posting the same question again.

Comment: I'd say lets not be so critical, the interface could be confusing to some new users, so double posting could just be an accident. With the added image, the question became very clear and valid in my view, so I provided an answer.

Comment: @Lucian, I do agree that Q&A format is weird at first, and when a question gets closed it's not necessarily incredibly clear what you should do. What bothers me personally is users who post questions and don't try to have any kinda conversation about it and just let the question slowly fade away or possibly get closed. It's made even worse by posting a duplicate afterwards. — Not sure what you mean by an added image? It's the same exact post with the same image, It's just rotated this time.

Comment: What I mean is, in the original form of the duplicate, there was no image attached, and that was really vague. I also voted to close the other question, but then he did make an effort to come back, edit and post this sketch, which clarified the issue, and that's when I came up with my answer below.

Comment: @Lucian both questions have the same exact text and the same exact image. I don't know what you're saying. I don't know how posting a duplicate question shows effort. He showed some effort by editing the image into the old post, but I don't see how you see this _exact_ duplicate post as him putting any more effort into it.

Comment: When he first posted the first question, the image was not there (see edit history of the other question). The image was later added, which showed effort. He may have made it duplicate by accident, new users have not idea what a duplicate is really, but he did make the effort to provide more details, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Lucian, so how does posting a duplicate make it better?

Comment: What are you suggesting exactly ? :)

Comment: @Lucian, it sounded to me like you were implying this duplicate post was somehow an improvement from the original post because he edited the original post (before posting the duplicate). So you must then mean that this duplicate post adds something to the question. But I don't see how, given that the only difference ever was a rotated image in the duplicate post.

Comment: Its definitely a duplicate with the exact same content. I am just saying new users do not know the 'rules', or what a duplicate is, or what happens when a duplicate is posted by just not being aware of the rules. They will not be aware you and I will argue over this abstract idea which has zero connection to what's on that paper he took time to draw on. The duplicate is closed and that's done. Now, how do you plan on helping this person specifically ?

Comment: Hey @Joonas, sorry I wasn't as perfect and knowledgable at this as you are. I do not know all the rules, I do not know Illustrator, and reposted with the image because I thought that's what should be done.

Comment: @Lucian, thank you for your help and patience with the new people on here trying to learn.

Comment: OP: did you just open illustrator without even looking up some tutorials? We're here to help but this is a veery basic operation... Please check https://helpx.adobe.com/support/illustrator.html it will help you get through the first steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very detailed guide, but hopefully you can figure this out:

- create a new document and make it 7 × 5.1 inches
- hit <kbd>M</kbd> then click anywhere on the page and type 3.5 × 5.1 inches. Click Ok
- this creates a rectangle of 3.5 × 5.1 inches
- duplicate this by <kbd>Alt+dragging</kbd>, then you'll have two rectangles, each sized 3.5 × 5.1 inches
- select one rectangle and align **left & top** to artboard
- same thing for the other rectangle, **right & top** to artboard alignment
- hit <kbd>A</kbd> then select the corners and move their Y value to 1.175 inches (top corners) and 3.925 inches (bottom corners)

[image: illustration of original sketch]